# Configure Clef with Private Geth node

Tags: go-ethereum

In the latest [Geth release v1.11.0](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.11.0) `personal` namespace is being deprecated in favor of `Clef`.
I am using the `personal` namespace for account creation/unlock/lock etc. I want to integrate `Clef` with the private/local `Geth` node first.

My question is that is it possible to run Clef with a private node? if yes, then what should be passed as `--chainid` in the `Clef` startup command

```
./clef --keystore /path/to/keystore --chainid ?
```

I am trying to start the Private `Geth` note with `--dev` mode & to connect with `Clef` i am passing `--signer`. `Geth` complains that `--dev` & `--signer` cannot be run together. Does it mean `Clef` cannot be integrated with the `Private Geth` node?

I have been following this documentation https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/tools/clef/introduction#installing-and-starting-clef & struggling to get `Clef` & `Geth` running together.

Command to start Geth private node

```
 ./geth --dev --dev.period 5 --mine --syncmode "snap" --http --http.addr 0.0.0.0 --http.vhosts=localhost --verbosity 2 --http.api eth,web3,personal,debug,net --ws --ws.addr 0.0.0.0 --ws.origins=localhost --ws.api eth --allow-insecure-unlock --db.engine=pebble --datadir /path/to/datadir --signer=./clef/clef.ipc
```

Any help/guidance will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue. First of all i think private & dev node are different things. Private node can have multiple nodes but dev node is single node setup which is just for testing & data is lost after stopping the node.

I also observed that signer flag cannot be passed with dev flag.

- In my case, when i run geth with dev flag a random key store is generated in `/tmp`(Eg - `/tmp/go-ethereum-keystore494402999`).
- I run `clef newaccount --keystore /tmp/go-ethereum-keystore494402999` to generate new account for geth node.
- Confirm account is created by running `eth.accounts` in js console.
- Open js console by running `geth attach /tmp/geth.ipc`.
- I used https://www.myetherwallet.com/wallet to generate private key from keystore after entering password which i used in clef account creation.
- This private key can be directly used.

Above approach is not safe for production environment but there's some quick changes in geth after merger causing alot of bugs & issues.